# QRegularExpression count number of occurrences

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I have a QString and I want to count 2 things in QString:

a) Number of special chars

b) Number of consecutive 2 chars

For first one I tried this:

```
QRegularExpression var1("[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-]");
myString.count(var1);
```

Which I don't know how to also count backslash and slash chars and I'm not sure if this is the way to check for **ALL** special chars.

For second one I tried this:

```
QRegularExpression var2("([a-z\\d])\\1\\1");
myString.count(var2);
```

and also this:

```
QRegularExpression var2("([a-zA-Z0-9\\d])\\1\\1");
myString.count(var2);
```

Which doesn't work at all.

Please advice, I need number of consecutive chars and number of special chars in QString.

Comment: Have you tried just plain iteration of the string characters? This is a O(n) problem. I'm not certain why you are trying to use regular expressions here.

Comment: @user3427419 That would be time and code consuming! I need other stuff too, like number of upper case, number of lower case, number of digits and checking and counting every char I think would be too hard without regex. I took care of others, they work, just these two are the problems

Comment: Use QSet<QChar> for stuff you want to match? It's about 3 lines to match against your special characters (1 or 10000).

Comment: @user3427419, how do you count number of occurred chars in QSet<QChar> within QString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For first one. Please try this.

```
  QRegularExpression var1("[$&+,:;=?@#|'<>.^*()%!-/\\\\]");
```

You can count slash by just 1 slash like other char.
To cound backslash char, You need 4 backslashs. In regular expression, you need to escape backslash char  to match backslash char(\\). And in C++, you also need to escape those 2 backslashs. As a result, you need 4 backslashes.

For second one, you need just one \\1 to match consecutive 2 chars. \\1 means the same char of first matched group so your regex actually matches consecutive 3 chars.

```
  QRegularExpression var2("([a-z\\d])\\1");
```